# C++20 how to deal with multi-leveled unordered_map

Tags: c++, nested, c++20, unordered-map

I have a complex multi-layered dictionary in Python, and I want to know how to "translate" such thing to C++. I am just a beginner in C++ so I use C++20 standard, my IDE is Visual Studio 2022 and I want to know if in C++20 there is a simpler way to do it.

In this example, the first level keys are strings, and the first level values are all dictionaries of similar structures. The second level keys are all strings, but the values can be integers, lists and dictionaries. If the third level is a list, it is a list of integers, else if the last structure is a dictionary, it is a dictionary mapping integers to integers.

Example in Python:

```py
{
    "         ": {
        "over": False,
        "wins": 131184,
        "ties": 46080,
        "legal_moves": [
            0,
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6,
            7,
            8
        ],
        "win_moves": {
            0: 14652,
            1: 14232,
            2: 14652,
            3: 14232,
            4: 15648,
            5: 14232,
            6: 14652,
            7: 14232,
            8: 14652
        },
        "tie_moves": {
            0: 5184,
            1: 5184,
            2: 5184,
            3: 5184,
            4: 4608,
            5: 5184,
            6: 5184,
            7: 5184,
            8: 5184
        },
        "high_stakes": {
            0: 9468,
            1: 9048,
            2: 9468,
            3: 9048,
            4: 11040,
            5: 9048,
            6: 9468,
            7: 9048,
            8: 9468
        }
    }
}
```

The example shows all ways the first player can win from the starting state in Tic-Tac-Toe, I have computed this for all 5478 states reachable from the starting start if player O moves first, I have also computed the same if the other moves first, for a total of 8533 states.

The data shows whether the game is over, all ways player O can win from the state, and all ways the state can lead to a tie state, all legal moves, and for each move all possible ways the move can lead to a win, or a tie. `"high_stake"` means all possible ways the player can win minus all possible ways the game ends in a tie, negative values are set to 0.

I computed them in Python several days ago, I didn't use C++ because I don't know how to declare this structure in C++.

In C++ syntax, the data would be:

```cpp
{
    {"         ", {
        {"over", 0},
        {"wins", 131184},
        {"ties", 46080},
        {"legal_moves", {
            0,
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6,
            7,
            8
        }},
        {"win_moves", {
            {0, 14652},
            {1, 14232},
            {2, 14652},
            {3, 14232},
            {4, 15648},
            {5, 14232},
            {6, 14652},
            {7, 14232},
            {8, 14652}
        }},
        {"tie_moves", {
            {0, 5184},
            {1, 5184},
            {2, 5184},
            {3, 5184},
            {4, 4608},
            {5, 5184},
            {6, 5184},
            {7, 5184},
            {8, 5184}
        }},
        {"high_stakes", {
            {0, 9468},
            {1, 9048},
            {2, 9468},
            {3, 9048},
            {4, 11040},
            {5, 9048},
            {6, 9468},
            {7, 9048},
            {8, 9468}
        }}
    }
    }
}
```

What would be the type identifier of this monstrosity? Know I have 5477 other such structures in the same dictionary.

I know how to declare the individual objects:

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>


using std::unordered_map
using std::string

unordered_map<int, int> high_stakes = {
            {0, 9468},
            {1, 9048},
            {2, 9468},
            {3, 9048},
            {4, 11040},
            {5, 9048},
            {6, 9468},
            {7, 9048},
            {8, 9468}
        };


unordered_map<string, unordered_map<int, int>> d1 = {{"high_stakes", {
            {0, 9468},
            {1, 9048},
            {2, 9468},
            {3, 9048},
            {4, 11040},
            {5, 9048},
            {6, 9468},
            {7, 9048},
            {8, 9468}
        }}};

unordered_map<string, int[9]> d2 = {{"legal_moves", {
            0,
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6,
            7,
            8
        }}};
```

How can I declare these objects? I am going to compute the results in C++, and serialize the objects to a file. The statistics will be computed once, and other C++ programs will deserialize the results.

How can I guarantee the type won't be changed? I know I can't use JSON or any human-readable text based serialization format. I actually used pickle to store the data and that is what my Python program actually loads. What binary serialization format provided by the ***C++ standard library*** should I use for this purpose?

---

I know JSON cannot have integers as keys, I need the integer keys stay integers. Plus, I have benchmarked it, JSON serialization is slow.

Comment: json libraries might help (either as solution or as inspiration).

Comment: "_What binary serialization format provided by the C++ standard library should I use for this purpose?_:" There is none. You have to come up with a format yourself and provide the serialization/deserialization, or use a third-party library that already implements that.

Comment: "_know I can't use JSON or any human-readable text based serialization format._": Why not? That would be the easiest solution and many JSON libraries exist.

Comment: `int[9]` should probably be `std::array<int, 9>`.

Comment: *"but the values can be integers, lists and dictionaries"* `std::variant` might help.

Comment: I think the only real solution is to first study C++ and its standard library more. Understand it strengths (and weaknesses). Binary serialization is not easy in C++ and you best use an existing serialization library for that (e.g. flatbuffers or protobuf). Looks like you might use something like `std::map<std::string, std::variant<int,std::vector<int>>>`

Comment: In general in C++ try to be as typesafe as possible and come up with datastructures that don't mix types either. So instead of porting your "python" data structure to C++ try to design a new fully type safe one. So instead of asking HOW to port explain WHAT you want to have modeled

Comment: Learn what typealiases are, they help organizing such monstrosites, e.g. this way https://godbolt.org/z/re6hhsW68 However, there is not a single good or bad answer.
Also, maybe incorporating some third-party like Boost::MultiIndex can help you simplify that datastructure a bit. Either way, I second what @PepijnKramer has written: do some reading (sorry) and choose what suits you  best, there is no direct translation from Python

Comment: As for serialization, I would probably go with Google's protobuf, as a proven in use solution (one of many, another one being Boost::Serialization), but it by no means belongs to the standard library. Not that any actual serialization method did, but that's another story...

Comment: @alagner Usually I don't even use type aliases. I just make a wrapper class with a limited set of public methods (derived from an abstract baseclasss, so I can inject stuff in unit tests). Not much work either and then you have a strong type (which is harder to misuse)

Comment: Did you try **boost.json**? There are other open-source libraries too. But if I wanted to reinvent the wheel, that would most likely become like **boost.json**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Boost PropertyTree](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.propertytree) library. It has a JSON parser to convert an input JSON file to a `boost::property_tree::ptree` object. You can add and access nodes easily.

If you don't want to start from a JSON, you can manually add nodes to a `boost::property_tree::ptree`. [Since Python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6), `dict` preserves the insertion order, which makes `Boost Property` an ideal counterpart in C++. I think the keys and values are defaulted to `string`s upon retrieval, but you can easily cast type with the utility function `get_value<T>()`.

Anyway, here is an example [Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfc3f0a0832a1673) based on your JSON-like input with a few modifications,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>

namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

int main() {
  std::string json_str = R"(
  {
      "info": {
          "over": false,
          "wins": 131184,
          "ties": 46080.5,
          "legal_moves": [
              0,
              1
          ],
          "win_moves": {
              "0": 14652,
              "1": 14232
          }
      }
  }
  )";

  // Parse the JSON string
  std::stringstream json_stream(json_str);
  pt::ptree root;
  pt::read_json({json_stream}, root);

  // Access value of a leave node
  {
    auto over = root.get_child("info").get_child("over").get_value<bool>();
    std::cout << "over = " << over << std::endl;
  }

  // boolean
  auto over = root.get_child("info.over").get_value<bool>();
  std::cout << "over = " << over << std::endl;

  // integer number
  auto wins = root.get_child("info.wins").get_value<int>();
  std::cout << "wins = " << wins << std::endl;

  // floating-point number
  auto ties = root.get_child("info.ties").get_value<double>();
  std::cout << "ties = " << ties << std::endl;

  // array of numbers
  std::cout << "legal_moves:\n";
  for (const auto &it : root.get_child("info.legal_moves")) {
    std::cout << it.second.get_value<int>() << std::endl;
  }

  // nested object
  std::cout << "win_moves:\n";
  for (const auto &it : root.get_child("info.win_moves")) {
    auto key = it.first;
    auto val = it.second.get_value<int>();
    std::cout << key << " : " << val << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Note that `boost::property_tree::read_json()` preserves the original order of values, while another popular package [JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) will sort the values due to the underlying `std::map<>` container.

I modified your original JSON-like string a bit:

1. `boost::property_tree::read_json()` requires that JSON keys be `string`s.
2. If you insist on using `"         "` as a key, call `get_child("         ").get_child("...")` to get child nodes.
3. `False` => `false` to allow `get_value<bool>()`; otherwise, you have to parse it as a `string` and then convert to `bool` manually.